# How to refer to section*{Masi}?

Tags: cross-referencing

Assume you have

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

\section*{Methods}
Please, see Section \ref{section:lorem} for the evaluation of this topic.

\section*{Evaluation}
\label{section:lorem}

\end{document}
```

and you get

```
Please, see Section  for the evaluation of this topic.
                   |
                   two spaces so wrong and without the number
```

I do not know what is the policy in official papers to refer to the context in the text, since you cannot have the numbers for sections.

**What is the format of referring to other parts of the text in publications?**

Comment: Sorry, there is no number, how would you like to refer to it?

Comment: to whoever cast the "close" vote -- this question *does* have an answer (which has been posted below).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `\phantomsection` (from `hyperref`) to set an anchor at the proper location and, since there's no number to reference, you can use `\nameref` instead of `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{Methods}
Please, see Section \nameref{section:lorem} for the evaluation of this topic.

\phantomsection
\section*{Evaluation}
\label{section:lorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is exactly what I want.

Comment: This solution happens to be useful also for chapters and sections inside `backmatter` (book class), which otherwise are wrongly referred to as the last numbered sectioning element in `\mainmatter`.